# Fortran - Write and Read from same file using formats

Tags: file, format, fortran

The program is very stupid, but it is just a test to understand how reading from files works in Fortran. I wrote the following example:

```
program manipolazione
implicit none 
integer, parameter :: codice = 10
integer, parameter :: massimo = 20
integer :: numero, quadrato
integer :: error, errore_lettura
integer :: indice

010 format (1x, 'Il quadrato di ', I0, 1x, 'e'' ', I0)   
020 format(1x, A) ! scrive generico messaggio
030 format(1x, A, 1x, I0) ! scrive errori con loro codice
open (unit = codice, File = "test.txt", iostat = error, status = 'replace', action = 'write')
controllo_apertura : if (error == 0) then 
    write(*, 020) "Comincio a scrivere sul file...\n"
    contatore : do indice = 1, massimo, 1
        numero = indice
        quadrato = numero ** 2
        write(codice, 010) numero, quadrato
    end do contatore
else controllo_apertura
    write(*,020) "Non siamo riusciti ad aprire il file..."
end if controllo_apertura
close(codice)

open (unit = codice, File = "test.txt", iostat = error, status = 'old', action = 'read')
controllo_apertura1 : if (error == 0) then
    write(*,020)"Comincia la lettura dei valori!\n"
    counter : do indice = 1, massimo, 1
        read(codice, 010, iostat=errore_lettura) numero, quadrato ! THAT'S THE PROBLEM
        errorelettura : if (errore_lettura > 0) then 
            write(*,030) "Abbiamo avuto un problema serio, ho letto male, error:",errore_lettura
        else errorelettura
            write(*, 010) numero, quadrato
        end if errorelettura
    end do counter
else controllo_apertura1
    write(*,020) "Non siamo riusciti ad aprire il file..."
end if controllo_apertura1
read(*,*)
end program manipolazione
```

I would like to read what I have just written and print it back. In brief, write with a certain **format** and then read those values. By reading the code you will understand for sure. I really don't know what to do at line 29.

Comment: +1 for asking a FORTRAN question.

Comment: thanks!!! :) do you have any ideas to solve this format issue?

Comment: I barely remember my FORTRAN, so no, I can't help you with the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using this format statement

```
010 format (1x, 'Il quadrato di ', I0, 1x, 'e'' ', I0)
```

on this write statement

```
read(codice, 010, iostat=errore_lettura) numero, quadrato ! THAT'S THE PROBLEM
```

Your problem arises from trying to use a format statement which contains *character string edit descriptors*. The latest standard notes that these are not valid for input; I expect earlier standards also ruled them out.  They make perfect sense when writing but it's difficult to see how you want them to be interpreted on a read statement.  I'd try

```
011 format (2I0)
...
read(codice, 011, iostat=errore_lettura) numero, quadrato
```

and see what happens

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I knew they did not make any sense, I just wanted to point out that I wished to skip those characters to retrieve the numbers. Same error with your code: error 5006 in gfortran, which should mean wrong format. I really appreciate your help. Do you have any other hints to help me?

Comment: @AleN: Then you'll need a format that skips over the strings and reads just the numbers. This will be cumbersome, because you write them out as `I0`, the minimum width, meaning that their position on the line will vary with their size.